# Wordpress Media Library - how to "uncache" images

Tags: images

When doing a recent Google search we noticed that some of our images are being cached by Google but the link that is attached to them is the actual media library link.  So when you click on that link, it shows a really "ugly" page because this page is not really published and is the template.

Is there any way to make images that we upload to our Media Library unsearchable or keep them out of being cached by Google?

Comment: Can you post a sample link thats being indexed?

Answer (score 1):

You could `noindex, nofollow` your `\wp-content\uploads\` directory?

Comment: How would I add this to that one folder?  Sorry just confused -and thank you for the help!

Comment: By adding a `robots.txt` file to that directory?